# Accessing HTML5 Local Storage from Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, local-storage

Is there any way to access HTML5 Local Storage from Ruby On Rails application? If there is any gem/javascript library (excepting backbone.js, because it is too difficuilt to rewrite existing app using it), please give me a link and good tutorial. And if you have your own code , that solves this problem, I'll be also happy :) Thanks!

Comment: You are conflating Ruby on Rails (a server technology) with LocalStorage, which is client side.  The only way the server component can get to the local storage data is if it is posted down by the client via ajax.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `localStorage` is pure `Javascript/HTML5` feature. there is nothing to do with rails

You can use the following in you application javascript in order to read or write data from the local storage:

```
$('.add-hotel').click(function(){ 
item = localStorage.getItem('bucket_data');
});
```

Comment: You can use it by using ajax in your ruby code. if you need to know how to do this via AJAX , Let me know I will explain it.